# Am I able to remove "possible duplicate" tag from my question?

Tags: support, editing, asking-questions, duplicates

OK: I asked the [question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/50004/how-can-i-take-product-shots-of-a-flat-but-not-absolutely-flat-reflective-surf) and someone suggested that it was a duplicate (which is not if read the question and the suggested answers carefully). So now I have my question with "possible duplicate" tag in the top of my question.

I'd be happy to remove one as I'm afraid that visitors will skip my question without going deep into it.

Am I able to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the question has now been closed as a duplicate.  That message *does* show up for everyone.

That's not necessarily permanent, though. If you edit the question to clarify more obviously how the previous question *doesn't* cover the same thing, it can be reopened.

Comment: That is funny! People doesn't reading question carefully but they close it as duplicate?! Despite the fact I'm indicated that in the comments? What a pity... (it's not questions, just feel angry with that)

Comment: I read the question and I still felt like the other answers pretty much covered what you need to do — you don't need to avoid the literal camera reflection, but the basic idea is really similar.

Comment: Also, some of the votes to close probably came in _before_ your comment. And, commenting doesn't have the effect of throwing the question back into the queue for possible reopening — editing does.

Answer (score 3):

That message is only visible to you and is there t alert you tothe fact that there might already be answers to your question on that thread, or that it is not particularly obvious why your question is different to the linked question, so you can adjust to clarify.